# Count in Firebase JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, count, firebase-realtime-database

I have a sample JSON object below:

```
{
  "product" : [ {
    "description" : "This ball has air it.",
    "id" : "product0",
    "name" : "football",
    "price" : 10
  }, {
    "description" : "Can kick upto long distance.",
    "id" : "product1",
    "name" : "soccer boots",
    "price" : 5
  }, {
    "description" : "Long socks",
    "id" : "product2",
    "name" : "stockings",
    "price" : 2
  }, {
    "description" : "This ball has air it.",
    "id" : "product3",
    "name" : "gloves",
    "price" : 3
  }, {
    "description" : "Wear it pls.",
    "id" : "product4",
    "name" : "jersey",
    "price" : 12
  } ]
}
```

What can be the shortest way to find the number (count) of products in JavaScript? Does Firebase provide any query in JavaScript to find the count in an object?

Comment: `JSON.parse(jsonObject).product.length`

Comment: No need to add a code snippet if it does nothing.

Comment: Firebase has recently released Cloud Functions. Have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42713792/5861618) for more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple solution. Just get the `length` of required array from the JSON Object.

```js
var json = {
  "product": [{
    "description": "This ball has air it.",
    "id": "product0",
    "name": "football",
    "price": 10
  }, {
    "description": "Can kick upto long distance.",
    "id": "product1",
    "name": "soccer boots",
    "price": 5
  }, {
    "description": "Long socks",
    "id": "product2",
    "name": "stockings",
    "price": 2
  }, {
    "description": "This ball has air it.",
    "id": "product3",
    "name": "gloves",
    "price": 3
  }, {
    "description": "Wear it pls.",
    "id": "product4",
    "name": "jersey",
    "price": 12
  }]
};

console.log(json.product.length);
```

**Incase of JSON string:** Get the `length` like this

```js
var json = '{  "product" : [ {"description" : "This ball has air it.","id" : "product0","name" : "football","price" : 10  }, {"description" : "Can kick upto long distance.","id" : "product1","name" : "soccer boots","price" : 5  }, {"description" : "Long socks","id" : "product2","name" : "stockings","price" : 2  }, {"description" : "This ball has air it.","id" : "product3","name" : "gloves","price" : 3  }, {"description" : "Wear it pls.","id" : "product4","name" : "jersey","price" : 12  } ]}';

var t = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(t.product.length);
```

Comment: Thank you... This is very simple :)  @Pugazh

Answer (score 0):

You can save the object on JavaScript variable

```
var myData = {
  "product" : [ {
    "description" : "This ball has air it.",
    "id" : "product0",
    "name" : "football",
    "price" : 10
  }, {
    "description" : "Can kick upto long distance.",
    "id" : "product1",
    "name" : "soccer boots",
    "price" : 5
  }, {
    "description" : "Long socks",
    "id" : "product2",
    "name" : "stockings",
    "price" : 2
  }, {
    "description" : "This ball has air it.",
    "id" : "product3",
    "name" : "gloves",
    "price" : 3
  }, {
    "description" : "Wear it pls.",
    "id" : "product4",
    "name" : "jersey",
    "price" : 12
  } ]
}
```

Now you can get length

```
console.log(myData.product.length);
```